Automating Frontmatter Removal: Streamlining Hugo and AsciiDoctor PDF Integration
Hugo removes the frontmatter from an Asciidoc file before passing the document to the Asciidoc processor. For example
---
title:
subtitle:
...
__

But how can I hide the frontmatter for Hugo for Asciidoctor PDF if asciidoctor-pdf is to generate the PDF? Without having to comment out the first lines?
Is there a way to automate this?
Conversely, it is possible to adapt individual parameters to Hugo in Asciidoc. See Path Predicament: Navigating Image Rendering Discrepancies Between AsciiDoctor PDF and Hugo

The solution is so simple: Asccidoctor-pdf only needs one additional attribute when translating an adoc file into a PDF:
-a skip-front-matter

skip-front-matter attribute
